# Mendeley Generated Bib Entry @article Not Citable

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, natbib

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/105868/cannot-generate-bibliography-using-texworks-from-miktex) I get most of the following example references. With the third entry `@article` generated by Mendeley.

```
%File mb-bibtex.tex, then \jobname = mb-bibtex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}        % loading package filecontents
% writing file \jobname.bib, for example mb-bibtex.bib.
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{companion,
  author    = {Goossens, Michel and Mittelbach, Frank and Samarin, Alexander},
  title     = {The LaTeX Companion},
  edition   = {1},
  publisher = {Addison-Wesley},
  location  = {Reading, Mass.},
  year       = {1994}
}
@Book{adams,
  title     = {The Restaurant at the End of the Universe},
  author    = {Douglas Adams},
  series    = {The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy},
  publisher = {Pan Macmillan},
  year      = {1980}
}
@article{KESSLER2003d,
    author = {KESSLER, BRETT},
    doi = {10.1080/02702710390227228},
    file = {:Z$\backslash$:/Mendeley Literature/KESSLER/Reading Psychology/KESSLER - 2003 - Is English Spelling Chaotic Misconceptions Concerning Its Irregularity.pdf:pdf},
    issn = {0270-2711},
    journal = {Reading Psychology},
    number = {3-4},
    pages = {267--289},
    title = {{Is English Spelling Chaotic? Misconceptions Concerning Its Irregularity}},
    url = {http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/02702710390227228},
    volume = {24},
    year = {2003}
}
\end{filecontents*}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}         % bibliography style
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}    % better urls in bibliography

\begin{document}
Test of bibliography: 
The \LaTeX{} companion~\cite{companion}, the funny book of Adams~\cite{adams}. 

**The other citations work, but the Mendeley reference ~\cite{KESSLER2003d} does not. Perhaps it is a feature of the number of attributes generated?**

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}  % needs package natbib
\bibliography{\jobname}       % uses \jobname.bib, according to \jobname.tex
\end{document}
```

The first two show up as `[2], the funny book of Adams [1]` but the third shows up as `[? ]` at least on my system.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?  Your sample document compiles without error for me. Of course since the Mendelay author is in all upper case, it ends up like that in the output too. (Also, putting the entire title in an extra set of curly brackets isn't recommended).

Comment: Revised original post, "The first two show up as `[2], the funny book of Adams [1]` but the third shows up as `[? ]` at least on my system."

Comment: Like @AlanMunn, I am unable to reproduce the issue you say you're encountering. Specifically, as one would expect, `\cite{KESSLER2003d}` generates a `[3]` numeric citation callout. After adding the `\cite` instruction, did you remember to re-run BibTeX before recompiling the document with LaTeX?

Comment: @Mico I am sorry. I am not sure how to re-run BibTex. I am using TeXstudio and just hitting the compile button.

Comment: @fsmart - For sure, "hitting the compile button" will (by default) simply re-run LaTeX, but not re-run BibTeX as well. Unfortunately, I'm not a TeXstudio user, so I can't give you any direct advice on what you should do to run BibTeX.  Quick question: Doesn't the TeXstudio program come with a "Help" facility?! I can't imagine that it doesn't. Bringing up the help dialogue box, typing "BibTeX", and seeing what you get in terms of suggestions should almost certainly take a lot less time than posting a query on this site, shouldn't it?